# How do I change the name of titles that are inside a drawer in react navigation?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

Due to the app being for a different language, I would like for the titles that appear in the drawer to appear in a different language. Currently, they default to the routes that they're set to.  So instead of saying "Login" I would like "s'identifier" as an example.

Currently, drawer setup looks like this:

```
const allDrawerOptions = {
    NotificationHistory: { screen: NotificationHistory, },
    CameraRegistration: { screen: CameraRegistration, },
    Settings: { screen: Settings, },
    Info: { screen: Info, }
};

const drawerForNotificationHistory = DrawerNavigator(
    allDrawerOptions,
    { initialRouteName: 'NotificationHistory' }
);

const hamburgerIcon = ({ navigation }) => ({
  headerLeft:
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle')}
        style={{
            height: '100%',
            width: 60,
            // marginLeft: 10,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            // borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red',
        }}
    >
        <Text
            style={{
                fontFamily: 'FontAwesome',
                fontSize: 25,
            }}
        ></Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
});
```

and my stacknavigator looks like this:

```
const Navigation = StackNavigator(
    {
        Splash: { screen: Splash },
        Login: { screen: Login },
        SignUp: { screen: SignUp },
        HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
        Home: { screen: Home },
        NotificationHistory: {
            screen: drawerForNotificationHistory,
            navigationOptions: hamburgerIcon,

        },
     },
     initialRoute: 'HomeScreen'
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

They key was to add navigationOptions for each screen inside allDrawerOptions.

so NotificationHistory now looks like

```
NotificationHistory: 
    { screen: NotificationHistory,
        navigationOptions: () => 
            ({
                title: '알림 내역'
            }) 
    },
```